# OSXに導入したEmacsへ文字の入力ができない問題

Tags: macos, emacs

**経緯**
macbookproにEmacs-24.5の導入を試みました。
Homebrewを利用してインストール。しかし、いざEmacsを呼び出してみると,GNU Emacsの画面は立ち上がるものの、キーボード入力がターミナルに入力されてしまう現象が発生しました。

**環境**
OSX Yosemite 10.10.5
Homebrew 0.9.5 (git revision f211; last commit 2015-10-24)

**やったこと**
以下のサイト様を参考にしながら、順にコマンドを実行していきました。
[OSXにHomebrewでtmuxとEmacs 24.4をインストールする - Qiita](http://qiita.com/masato/items/ef0ffa626ca8bf46bf8a)

tmuxの導入は今回行っていません。

まず、Homebrew installを実行してEmacsを導入しました。

> $ brew install --with-cocoa emacs

無事にWarningやErrorが特に発生することなく、インストール終了しました。
この時点でEmacsの起動を試みます。

> $ emacs

すると、ターミナルのウィンドウの下にGNU Emacsが起動しました。ターミナルがアクティブのままです。
EmacsのウィンドウをクリックするとEmacsアクティブがアクティブになってくれたので、試しにC-x,C-fを入力しました。すると、Emacsではなくターミナル上に入力が表示されてしまいました。

[image: emacs起動中にターミナルへ入力される文字]

クリックやドラッグ操作によってツールバーからファイルを開いたり、文字列のコピーなどを行うことはできました。しかし、キーボード入力は依然としてターミナルに入力されてしまいます。

この状態でC-cを入力すると、emacsを終了することができました。
その際、ターミナル上に次のようなメッセージが出力されました。

> 2015-10-24 19:55:03.462 emacs[91392:1443732] *** -[NSAutoreleasePool release]: This pool has already been released, do not drain it (double release).

このメッセージは、GNU Emacsのウィンドウにある閉じるボタンを押してEmacsを終了させた場合には表示されません。

そして次に、Emacs.appが起動できるかを確かめるために、参考サイトに倣って/Applicationsへシムリンクを作成しました。

> $ brew linkapps emacs
>   Linking /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.5/Emacs.app to /Applications.
>
> $ open /Applications/Emacs.app

すると、無事にGNU Emacsが起動しました。しかし、依然としてターミナルからEmacsを呼びだしてもキーボード入力は通りませんでした。

**知りたいこと**

- ターミナルから立ち上げたemacsに文字を入力できない問題の解決策、または考えられる原因
- 類似症例の報告。その症例の解決や対処に使った方法

質問文に不足項目があれば対応させていただきます。よろしくお願いします。

追記1：2015-10-24 21:57
command+tab で起動中のアプリケーションの一覧表示・切り替えができますが、その中にターミナルから立ち上げたEmacsは表示されていませんでした。起動中のアプリケーションとして認識されていないということでしょうか……

Comment: ターミナルから `emacs -q --eval '(x-focus-frame nil)'` を実行するとどうなりますか？

Comment: scratch画面が立ち上がりました。しかし、症状としては変わりなく、入力した文字はターミナルに表示されてしまいました。終了に関する動作も同様でした。

Comment: どうもありがとうございます。お手数ですが、今度は `emacs -q --eval '(progn (sleep-for 5) (x-focus-frame nil))'` を試していただけますか？ 5秒程度待ってからキー入力を行ってみて下さい。

Comment: 繰り返しの提案ありがとうございます。emacsのウィンドウが立ち上がってから5秒ほどでscratch画面に切り替わりました。症状の改善は特に見られませんでした。

Comment: 了解です。またなにか判りましたらコメントします。

Answer (score 1):

brewからemacsをインストール後、全く同じ問題に遭遇しました。
`/usr/local/bin/emacs-25.3`
を実行していましたが、
`/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/25.3/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs`
にすることで解決しました。自分への忘備録として投稿します。